# Apache POI : Update cells in a named range

Tags: java, apache-poi, xlsx

I am using Apache POI library to read/write to xlsx. In my original xlsx, I have a namedrange "XYZ".

I want to update the values of cells within this name range. How can I do that?
I did this:

```
XSSFName name = workbook.getName("XYZ");
String formula = name.getRefersToFormula();
System.out.println("Formula = " + formula);
```

Now, I dont know how to get a  handle to individual cell in this named range.

Can anyone please point me to the correct API that I can use?

Rgds
Sapan

Answer (score 7):

There is an example from the [Busy Developers' Guide](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#NamedRanges) for retrieving the cells in the range. Then you can use Cell.setCellValue() to update.

```
// setup code
String cname = "TestName";
Workbook wb = getMyWorkbook(); // retrieve workbook

// retrieve the named range
int namedCellIdx = wb.getNameIndex(cname);
Name aNamedCell = wb.getNameAt(namedCellIdx);

// retrieve the cell at the named range and test its contents
AreaReference aref = new AreaReference(aNamedCell.getRefersToFormula());
CellReference[] crefs = aref.getAllReferencedCells();
for (int i=0; i<crefs.length; i++) {
    Sheet s = wb.getSheet(crefs[i].getSheetName());
    Row r = s.getRow(crefs[i].getRow());
    Cell c = r.getCell(crefs[i].getCol());
    // extract the cell contents based on cell type etc.
}
```